# Add new button in kendo grid edit popup mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I want to add a button kendo grid edit popup mode ( kendo web asp.net mvc razor)

[image: What I want to get]

example : I have 2 table with relationship one(table A) -many (table B)
now user click add new B, in pop-up edit have a drop-down show A, next to drop-down i want to add new button to add new A without navigate direct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define in your columns definition an [editor](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnseditor-function) function that generates both elements (the checkbox as it is being added and the button).

Example:

```
{
    field   : "selected",
    title   : "Selected",
    template: "<input type='checkbox' name='selected' #= selected ? 'checked' : '' # disabled/>",
    editor : generateButton
}
```

and `generateButton` is:

```
function generateButton(container, options) {
    container.append('<input type="checkbox" name="' + options.field + '" data-type="boolean" data-bind="checked:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .append('<a href="#" id="mybutton" class="k-button">Button</a>');
}
```

Example in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/HkTL2/)

Comment: thank for your reply but i use MVC so how can i do like you
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.PKiServiceID).Groupable(false).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SServiceName).Width(250);
        columns.Bound(p => p.BStatus).Width(70).ClientTemplate("#if(BStatus){# #='Y'# #} else {# #='N'# #}#");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
    })
    )
)